# How to display array of items in row format when exporting to Excel?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have to export this to XLSX file only.
I want to know how to export in form of rows. My code right now is displaying in columns with comma separation in between and I want to change that into rows.

The display before is:

```
{
    -------------------------------------------------
    |Header1|Header2|Header3|Header4|Header5|Header6|
    |-------------------------------------------------
    |A,A,A,A|B,B,B,B|C,C,C,C|D,D,D,D|E,E,E,E|F,F,F,F|
    --------------------------------------------------
}
```

Should be displayed Like this:

```
{
    |Header1|Header2|Header3|Header4|Header5|Header6|
    |-------------------------------------------------
    |A      |B      |C      |D      |E      |F
    |-------------------------------------------------
    |A      |B      |C      |D      |E      |F
    |-------------------------------------------------
    |A      |B      |C      |D      |E      |F
    |-------------------------------------------------
    |A      |B      |C      |D      |E      |F

}
```

Angular:

```
list = list.map(function (x) {
     item['temp_1'] = item['temp1'].map((x) => {
            for (let key of Object.keys(item.temp1)) {
                key = x.temp1Name;
                    return key;
            

        }
    }
}
```

JSON:

```
temp_1: Array(3)
0: "AAAA"
1: "BBBB"
2: "CCCC"
```

Comment: You could make a CSV file.

Comment: No I have to export into XLSX only